# showing egg shaped images from fancybox

Tags: css, fancybox, fancybox-2

I want to remove that white background and show whole image in fixed width size using fancy box, as of now it is showing egg shaped image. am i missing some configuration changes ?

i am using fancyBox v2.1.5

and following libs

```
jquery.fancybox.css 
jquery.fancybox-buttons.css 
jquery.fancybox.css 
jquery.fancybox-thumbs.css 

jquery.fancybox.pack.js 
jquery.fancybox-buttons.js 
jquery.fancybox-media.js 
jquery.fancybox-thumbs.js
```

and css as

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
     $(".fancybox").fancybox({
    loop : false, "autoScale": false,
      buttons: [
    "zoom",    
    "slideShow",
    "thumbs",
    "close"
  ],
    AutoDimension: true,

});
 });
```

image for reference 
[image: Click here for Image]

Comment: That looks like some extra styling you may have added - never seen fancybox add a border like that around the popup.  Why not try inspecting the element to see what creates it and just delete that css from your stylesheets

Comment: @Pete you were correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally i found answer or cause for this problem.

i were showing thumbnail image with small size image 
having property of `border-radius:50 %` which it causing thumbnail image rounded corner and egg shaped image. Hence when we clicked on thumbnail it occupies same size as of thumbnail image in fancy box while opening. when i removed this property, problem solved. 
[image: sample image]